# Spotify NextAuth.js Not working INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI

Tags: authentication, spotify, next-auth

Hi Im using nextjs and nextauth for authentication I have google facebook and instagram all working and its very simple. Spotify does not want to work. When I click it to sign in I get INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI on the spotify dashboard i have the URI as "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/spotify" below is my code, Can someone point in me in the right direction

```
    import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook"
import LinkedInProvider from "next-auth/providers/linkedin"
import TwitterProvider from "next-auth/providers/twitter"
import InstagramProvider from "next-auth/providers/instagram"
import SpotifyProvider from "next-auth/providers/spotify"

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        }),
        LinkedInProvider({
            clientId: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET
        }),
        TwitterProvider({
            clientId: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET
        }),
        InstagramProvider({
            clientId: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET
        }),
        SpotifyProvider({
            clientId: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
            redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/spotify'
          
        }),
        FacebookProvider({
            clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/user',
    },
})
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the with the url in the redirect api i should of been

after that the authentication worked juts fine so it was a simple spelling error

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/spotify
```